# GSuite Alert Center API returns 'customer id could not be inferred from the request or caller identity.' error

Tags: node.js, google-workspace, google-alert-center-api

I am trying to get a list of alerts from the **GSuite Alert Center API** in a **Node JS** application.
I created a Service Account at the **IAM & Admin** page, checked the `Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation` checkbox, and generated a JSON file with access keys set.
Then I went to the `Admin Console -> Security -> API controls -> Domain-wide Delegation` and registered the Service Account by its Client ID with the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.alerts` scope.

The code was taken from the example provided in [google-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/src/apis/alertcenter/v1beta1.ts#L1650) and basically looks like

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const alertcenter = google.alertcenter('v1beta1');

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
   keyFile: 'Path/to/my/file/with/accessKeys'
   scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.alerts'],
});
const client = await auth.getClient();
google.options({auth: client});

const res = await alertcenter.alerts.list();
```

What I am getting back from the API is the **'customer id could not be inferred from the request or caller identity.'** error message.

I tried to pass the customer ID as a parameter to the list() method since it is described as its legit parameter. Like this

```
const res = await alertcenter.alerts.list({ customerId: 'my-customer-id' });
```

As a result, I only got another error message: **Request contains an invalid argument.**

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Hey I had this same issue and it drove me a bit mad.

I found that the authorisation needs a user email associated with the 'customer' that is required in the credentials. This email needs to be from an account of a user that has access to the alert center.

This is required in the 'subject' parameter of the authorisation credentials.

I couldn't do this through the GoogleAuth object as it doesnt, but through using the JWT, which is similar

I followed my nose from the python issue people had here
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/777

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.alerts'];
const credentials = require("Path/to/my/file/with/accessKeys");

// email with access to alert center
const auth_email = 'someemail@domain.com';

async function runSample() {
    const authClient = new google.auth.JWT({
        email:credentials.client_email,
        key: credentials.private_key,
        scopes: scopes,
        subject: auth_email 
    });

    authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            authClient.setCredentials(tokens);
        }
    });

    google.options({
        auth: authClient
    });

    const alertcenter = google.alertcenter('v1beta1');

    const res = await alertcenter.alerts.list();

    console.log(res.data);

    return res.data;
}

if (module === require.main) {
    runSample().catch(console.error);
  }
  
  // Exports for unit testing purposes
  module.exports = {runSample};
```

This is working for me now - there may be another way to assign the subject/email to the authorisation with `GoogleAuth`  but I can't figure it out.